# Possible to use UIAlertController on a modal view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I have a presented (modal) view controller that needs to present an action sheet. However when I do this:

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

...

[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I get this:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fed4a608120>  on <MyViewController: 0x7fed4d1ca520> which is already presenting (null)
```

Is there a workaround here? It seems like a pretty common scenario to use an alert or action sheet from a presented view controller.

Comment: Where and when are you trying to call the code in your question? Show more context.

Comment: @rmaddy it's when a button is pressed on the presented view controller.

Comment: This should work. The problem is not here. You can create a sample project that presents a modal which in turn presents an action sheet. If that fails, post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to show the action sheet from `viewDidLoad` of presenting view controller. That is the reason of not showing the action sheet in the controller as the controller's view is not yet loaded. So If you are doing so, then write those code to displaythe action sheet in your `voewDidAppear` method, the it will show you the action sheet as expected.

Here is the code snippet. I have tested it and it is working.

**Code :**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Hello" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }];

    [actionSheet addAction:ok];

    [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Happy coding ...